# javascript check if the input value duplicated?

Tags: javascript

How to check if inputted text value are duplicated ??

```
<%for(int i =0;i<5;i++){%>
<input type="text" id="time<%=i%>" onblur="fnValidate(<%=i%>,this.value)">
<%}%>
```

### javascript

i tried something like below sample, but logic is wrong.

```js
function fnValidate(count,value)
    {

      for(var i =0; i<5 ; i++)
      {
           if(i !== count && document.getElementById("time"+i).value == value)
             document.getElementById("time"+count).style.background ="#ff0000";
             else 
             document.getElementById("time"+count).style.background ="#fff";

      }

    }
```

```html
<input id="time0" onchange="fnValidate(0, this.value)">
<input id="time1" onchange="fnValidate(1, this.value)">
<input id="time2" onchange="fnValidate(2, this.value)">
<input id="time3" onchange="fnValidate(3, this.value)">
<input id="time4" onchange="fnValidate(4, this.value)">
```

Comment: Show your attempt to implement this function. Have you tried anything other than picking a function name?

Comment: please check updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that `i !== count` to skip current field.

```js
function fnValidate(current, value){
  var hasDuplicates = false

  for(var i =0; i<5 ; i++) {
   if(i !== current && document.getElementById("time"+i).value == value) {
    hasDuplicates = true
    break
   }
  }

  document.getElementById('time' + current).style.backgroundColor = hasDuplicates ? '#F00' : '#FFF'
}
```

```html
<input id="time0" onchange="fnValidate(0, this.value)">
<input id="time1" onchange="fnValidate(1, this.value)">
<input id="time2" onchange="fnValidate(2, this.value)">
<input id="time3" onchange="fnValidate(3, this.value)">
<input id="time4" onchange="fnValidate(4, this.value)">
```

Comment: hi yury, is there a way to put else statement for this?

Comment: @user3835327 Well, yes. I have removed it for demo to avoid annoying alerts that nothing found.

Comment: @user3835327 I have. As I wrote in my answer your logic is wrong because you do not skip current field. This piece of code `i !== count`  skips current field from checking.

Comment: yaya i replace the code you gave.. but the else statement seem not correct

Comment: @user3835327 Because now your logic is different you have to stop loop whenever you have found a duplicate. I have updated the answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: Thank alot Yury.. sorry for taking your time.

Comment: @user3835327 Hey, no problem. :) Glad I could help.